# 406(Not acceptable) .trying to return object or integer from spring handling function using @Responsebody to ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring, ajaxform

I used the following code in javascript:

```
function submit(){
    var form = $('#egform').serialize();
    alert("before ajax");
     $.post("testing.html", form, function(data, status) {
        if (data==1) {
            alert("Save successfull");
        } else {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });             
}
```

and in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("testing.html")
public @ResponseBody Integer gettestvalue(HttpServletRequest request){
    String a=request.getParameter("first");
    System.out.println(a);
    return 1;
}
```

but I am not getting the returned 1 to the javascript function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get returned? try a `console.log(data)` to see the return value

Comment: You are able to reach method `gettestvalue` while calling..?

Comment: Change int to Integer as your return type.

Comment: @Aakash but its not working

Comment: @gefei actually i got 406 error when i look on my console

Comment: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers. how to resolve this... pls help ....

Comment: Post the json you are sending with the request.

Comment: @Nishad You should [edit] this question and retag it appropriately (e.g. [tag:http-status-code-406]) to include that information (or simply do further research based on that new information) if you want to get a better response.

Comment: Are you sure you have Jackson mapper imported into your project?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk how can i check that in my project?

Comment: i think my spring configuration xml will help u to reach this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you're not using Maven, simply make sure [Jackson Mapper](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar) is imported into your project.

It wasn't necessary for me, but you may need the [core dependency](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar) as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Made sure to rebuild? Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Also make sure you have `<annotation-driven />` in your `servlet-context.xml`.

Comment: That would be it. Still the same problem? What have you changed exactly?